# Broadcasting with WiFi Direct in android

Tags: android, wifi-direct, broadcasting

I am beginner in android programming. Am trying to broadcast messages on WiFiDirect using the following code:

public class FileTransferService extends IntentService {

```
    public static final String host= "255.255.255.255";
    InetAddress broadcastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);// Exception: Unknown host exception
    int port = 8888;

        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG,"m in 1");
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    DatagramSocket socket;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        socket.setBroadcast(true);

            socket.connect(broadcastAddress, port);
            String message = "Hello";
            byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
            buffer, buffer.length, broadcastAddress, port);
            socket.send(packet); // <----- Causes a SocketException
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
          }
         }
```

It shows me unknown host exception on getByName() method. Is there anyway to replace the method? Am I going on a right path? Do I need to add anything along with this to send messages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: excuse me @user2645907 but which Android API are using? Android 4.x ? or below?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `public UnknownHostException (String detailMessage)` to get the [detailed exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) message.


Another way to call getByName() can be get from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29)

Below link has a step by step illustration of setting up a Wi-Fi Direct broadcaster
[Connecting with Wi-Fi Direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#receiver)